# Text shortcuts for faster communication

Tags: windows

I once worked as customer service representative for a big company. We had to be very fast at receiving calls and handling them. Most of the popular notes that we would put on user accounts were easily entered using some text like `#wlost` that would be replaced with the complete text required to note that the user lost his wireless device.

I am looking for some sort of program like this but cannot find anything, I am willing to spend time and program such a thing myself if needed but I wouldn't know where to start.

Comment: I think this can help http://www.hot-keyboard.com/docs/paste_help.htm

Comment: Related question: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/10176/autocorrect-anywhere-on-windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com) can do this and much more besides. It is a great tool for automating Windows. Pretty easy to learn with a BASIC-like syntax and loads of help and community support. It has been around nearly as long as Windows itself!

The part you are looking for is titled "[Hotstrings and Auto-replace](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm)" in the help. Examples are provided that are very close to your requirement.

Comment: Thank you, it is exactly what I needed. I have installed the script at the end of the page and I was done setting up in less than 10 minutes :)